# Boundary of epigraph

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry

Let $V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ be open and let $\phi: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous.  I want to understand whether it's true that $\partial\{x_n>\phi(x')\}=\{x_n=\phi(x')\}$. Call $U = \partial\{x_n>\phi(x')\}$. Here all the $x$s are assumed in $V\times \mathbb{R}$.

*Context*: I am finding a whole lot of definitions for $C^1$, Lipschitz and what not domains, and I want to understand their equivalence.

*My try*

- left inclusion: let $x \in \partial U$, find $y^k$ with $ y^k_n\leq \phi(y^{'k})$, converging to $x$, and $x^k$ with $ x^k_n< \phi(x^{'k})$, converging to $x$. Continuity implies $x_n\geq\phi(x'), x_n\leq\phi(x')$, so, $x_n=\phi(x')$
- right inclusion: let $x_n=\phi(x')$. Then, $x\notin U$, but it can be approximated by $x^k = x+\frac{k+1}{k}e_n$, which satisfies $x^k_n = x_n+\frac{k+1}{k}>x_n =\phi(x') = \phi(x^{'k}) $. Therefore $x \in \partial U$.

Is this correct?

I think no, because e.g. [here](https://mospace.umsystem.edu/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10355/9670/research.pdf), page 112, sets $\Omega$ with smooth boundaries are defined requiring more than $\Omega \cap \text{some parallelepiped}=\{x_n>\phi(x')\}$, and remark 4.6.5 further confuses me in this direction.

Comment: Just to clarify: By $\partial U$ you mean the topological boundary?

Comment: yes, @TedShifrin